# Вернуть строку, где элементы с четными индексами будут переведены в верхний регистр

Tags: javascript

Привет всем,

Суть задачи: написать функцию которая принимает в параметры строку, и возвращает её, где всё элементы с четными индексами переведены в верхний регистр.

Например:

```
 toWeirdCase( "Weird string case" );//=> returns "WeIrD StRiNg CaSe"
```

```js
function toWeirdCase(s){
    var str = s.toLowerCase().split(' '); // Переводим строку в нижний регистр, и разбиваем на массив. 
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){ // проходимся циклом по этим массивам
        var s = str[i].split('').forEach(function (item, j/*индекс текущего элемента*/) { // разбиваем уже сложенные элементы на массивы, и попутно делаем проверку на четность индекса
            if (j % 2 === 0){
                item.toUpperCase(); // переводим элемент с четным индексом в верхний регистр
                //console.log(item.toUpperCase()); // так выводит всё четные элемент в верхнем регистре.
            }
        });
        console.log(s);
    }
}

console.log(toWeirdCase("Weird string case"));
```

Вот не могу понять как теперь, собрать обратно всё в одну сроку.
Кто может ткните носом меня, в сторону правильного решения :)

Comment: создай внутри переменную, конкатенируй в неё данные, верни её из функции......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот решение вопроса без прохождения по двум циклам.

```html
    <script>
        function toWeirdCase(s){
            var str = s.toLowerCase().split(''); // Переводим строку в нижний регистр, и разбиваем на массив. 
            var j = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){ // проходимся циклом по этим массивам
                if(str[i] == ' '){
                    j = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    if (j % 2 == 0){
                        str[i] = str[i].toUpperCase(); // переводим элемент с четным индексом в верхний регистр
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
            return str.join('');
        }

        console.log(toWeirdCase("Weird string case"));
    </script>
```

В функции `split` если задать параметр пустую строку то он разрезает строку по символам, вот проходим по нему каждый четный символ переводим в верхний регистр, но не считаем прабелы.

Comment: Спасибо. Ваше решения оказалось самым подходящим для меня !

Comment: @Swartex Не за что.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function toWeirdCase(s) {
  var str = s.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < str[i].length; j++) {
      if (j % 2 === 0) {
        result += str[i][j].toUpperCase();
      } else {
        result += str[i][j];
      }
    }
    result += ' ';
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(toWeirdCase("Weird string case"));
```

Answer (score 1):

*зачем так громоздить?*
вот вариант на **регулярках**. правда немного растянуто, но что бы понятно было спец. так сделал.

```js
function replacer(str, $1, $2, offset, s) {
    return  $2.replace(/(.)(.)/gi, uper) + ' '; // ищем четное и нечетное и кидаем в uper
}

function uper (str, $1, $2, offset, s) {
    return  $1.toUpperCase()+$2; // берем первый символ делаем, большим плюсуем второй
}

const str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';

console.log(str.replace(/(^|\s*)(\w*)(^|\s*)/g, replacer)) // ищем слова и кидаем найденое в функцию replacer
```

Comment: Мне как начинающему отнюдь не проще :) но за  решение спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
function func(str){
      let res='';
      for(let i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if(i%2!==0){res+=str[i]};
        if(i%2==0){
            res+=str[i].toUpperCase();
        }   
      }
      return res;}

      console.log(func("Weird string case"));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]